# Editing documentation conflicts: Previous edits get overwritten

Tags: bug, edits, documentation

As edits on documentation work right now, there's *no* merging of conflicting edits going on.
The last edit that gets accepted will override anything that's been edited on there.

Example:

In the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/revisions/185?exampleId=714) on "Saying hello from JavaScript", I made 2 edits that add a link to a reference to Node.js. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/11924), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12561))

Both edits, while approved, were reverted by the edits following them. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/11985), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12984)). The second changeset doesn't even show the Node.js link as being removed. It's as if it's never existed.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I posted the wrong link. I remember having seen the same issue, but can't find it right now.